# Sum of values in each row of DataFrame

Tags: python, list, dataframe, split, sum

I have a csv file with 100 rows and only one column. Each row has many values and I want to find the sum of these values, but each row is being treated as one large integer.

How can I either split up my large dataset (delimiter?) into individual columns or sum up each value in each row without having to split it?

Ex. of how my file looks now

```
A     1100100101000112012110011
B     0000010100011000002000111
C     0010100000011000000101110
D     1100000110001011001001100
E     0000210000000000000010010
```

How I would like to look like:

```
                                    SUM
A     1100100101000112012110011     16
B     0000010100011000002000111     9
C     0010100000011000000101110     8
D     1100000110001011001001100     10
E     0000210000000000000010010     5
```

I am currently unable to get the sum since each row is looked at like one large number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation of code inside of `.apply`

- Each value in the `vals` column is a `str` type, not a numeric.
- Using [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) will separate the string into a list

```py
ex = list('1100100101000112012110011')

# print(ex)
[out]:
['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '2', '0', '1', '2', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1']
```

- Each value must be converted to an `int` with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), and then the list can be summed.

```py
print(list(map(int, ex)))
[out]:
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

### Code to read the csv and convert the column

- To read the given file, use [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and use `sep='\\s+'` to specify the separator.
- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to transform the column

```py
import pandas as pd

# given the sample csv
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='\\s+', header=None)
df.rename(columns={0: 'ID', 1: 'vals'}, inplace=True)

# transform the column with apply
df['SUM'] = df.vals.apply(lambda x: sum(map(int, list(x))))

# display(df)
  ID                       vals  SUM
0  A  1100100101000112012110011   16
1  B  0000010100011000002000111    9
2  C  0010100000011000000101110    8
3  D  1100000110001011001001100   10
4  E  0000210000000000000010010    5

# save the df
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution using list commprehension:

```
df['SUM'] = df.vals.map(lambda x: sum([int(i) for i in x]))
```

result `df`:

```
  id                       vals  SUM
0  A  1100100101000112012110011   16
1  B  0000010100011000002000111    9
2  C  0010100000011000000101110    8
3  D  1100000110001011001001100   10
4  E  0000210000000000000010010    5
```